# How to decrease the file name by 1 in ubuntu

Tags: files, batch-rename

I have around 200 `.png` files in my folder, naming like -

```
02.png
03.png
04.png
...
201.png
```

As you can see I dont have `01.png` so I want to rename the all files decreasing by one, to make it like -

```
01.png
02.png
03.png
...
200.png
```

Is it possible it to do it via any command in ubuntu ?

Following is the command I am trying with no luck -

```
rename -n '/d{2}\.png$d{2}-1\.png/' *.png
```

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't think as starting series is - 01, 02 .. and not like 1, 2 ...

Comment: you might want to refresh your screen, I retracted my vote a while ago, came to the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with a somewhat more complex `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/(\d{2,3}).png/sprintf("%02d", $1-1) . ".png"/e' *.png
```

Notes:

- You need to separate the match and the replacement with a `/`.
- You need to group the part you want to remember using `$1` with `()` (in this case `(\d{2,3})`).
- You should match both 2- and 3-digit numbers, or `100.png` will become `1-1.png`.
- To use an arithmetic or functions in the replacement, it should be evaluated as an expression, that's why there's a `e` after the closing `/`.
- To combine strings in an evaluated expression, you need to use `.` (hence `. ".png"`).
- To pad strings with zeros (presumably what you want, since your original files had them), use `sprintf`. `%02d` will pad with zeros if your number doesn't have at least two digits.

Example:

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d{2,3}).png/sprintf("%02d", $1-1) .  ".png"/e' *.png | head
02.png -> 01.png
03.png -> 02.png
04.png -> 03.png
05.png -> 04.png
06.png -> 05.png
07.png -> 06.png
08.png -> 07.png
09.png -> 08.png
100.png -> 99.png
101.png -> 100.png
```

---

Depending on the version of `rename`, it might have trouble renaming files if the target already exists. In such cases, a simple workaround is to create a temporary directory and rename/move the files there:

```
mkdir temp
rename -n 's/(\d{2,3}).png/sprintf("temp\/%02d", $1-1) . ".png"/e' *.png
```

Note that `/` after `temp` needs to be escaped, or it will be taken as the final `/` of a `s//` command.

Comment: Following is the output for the command - `01.png renamed as 00.png
02.png not renamed: 01.png already exists
03.png not renamed: 02.png already exists
`

Comment: @Nesh make a temp folder and rename+move to that folder: `mkdir temp; rename -n 's/(\d{2,3}).png/sprintf("temp\/%02d", $1-1) .  ".png"/e' *.png`.

Comment: @Nesh edited accordingly.